# Android views one by one

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add ImageViews to a layout from an ArrayList, but when there are too many views,
it starts to show some delay because it first loads every image and then applies them to the view. I need to know if there is a way to add them one by one to avoid delay.

I'm using this code.

```
ArrayList<String> pictures;

ImageView iv;

LinearLayout container;
for (int i = 0; i < pictures.size(); i++) {

    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    iv = new ImageView(getActivity());  

    iv.setLayoutParams(params);

    iv.setImageBitmap(pictures.get(i));
    container.addView(iv);
}
```

Comment: are you saving the images to the memory ?

Comment: Yes. In external storage.

Comment: In memory means that there is a an array of these pictures inside your app

Comment: I'm saving the path of each image in the Array so I apply them to the image view and the image view to the layout.

Comment: how many bitmaps can you eventually visualize in one screen?

Comment: are these images in a viewpager ?